# When is mu_a used in this STAN example?

Tags: r, bayesian, multilevel-analysis, stan

I'm looking at an example of a random effects model with 2 random effects fit by Peter Li demonstrating how get models fit in lmer into STAN. The code for this and the accompanying data are stored [here](https://github.com/stan-dev/example-models/blob/master/ARM/Ch.13/pilots.stan).What I don't understand is how mu_a and mu_b are ever used because a and b are drawn from normals centered at zero and there is no repositioning step.

```
data {
  int<lower=0> N; 
  int<lower=0> n_groups; 
  int<lower=0> n_scenarios; 
  int<lower=1,upper=n_groups> group_id[N];
  int<lower=1,upper=n_scenarios> scenario_id[N];
  vector[N] y;
} 
parameters {
  vector[n_groups] a;
  vector[n_scenarios] b;
  real mu_a;
  real mu_b;
  real<lower=0,upper=100> sigma_a;
  real<lower=0,upper=100> sigma_b;
  real<lower=0,upper=100> sigma_y;
}
transformed parameters {
  vector[N] y_hat;

  for (i in 1:N)
    y_hat[i] <- a[group_id[i]] + b[scenario_id[i]];
} 
model {
  mu_a ~ normal(0, 1);
  mu_b ~ normal(0, 1);
  a ~ normal(0, sigma_a);
  b ~ normal(0, sigma_b);
  y ~ normal(y_hat, sigma_y);
}
```

Comment: What is the model supposed to do?

Comment: My guess is that there is a typo here and it should read a ~ normal(mu_a,sigma_a) and similarly for b.

Comment: I agree with @TrynnaDoStat - in this example `mu_a` and `mu_b` are just random values drawn from $N(0, 1)$.

Comment: @TrynnaDoStat I also agree.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is a typo. Peter Li's github is saying this code is for a model in Chapter 13 of Gelman's *Data Analysis Using Regression Analysis and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models*. The name of the file is also called `pilots.stan` and there is only one model that I can see in this chapter that is about pilots (section 13.5 in the book I'm looking at).

This is the model specified in the book:

$y_i \sim N(\mu + \gamma_{ji} + \delta_{ki}, \sigma^2_y)$, for $i=1,...,n$.

$\gamma_j \sim N(0,\sigma_\gamma^2)$, for $j=1,...,J$

$\delta_k \sim N(0,\sigma_\delta^2)$, for $k=1,...,K$

The code you posted would be this model if instead of

```
model {
  mu_a ~ normal(0, 1);
  mu_b ~ normal(0, 1);
  a ~ normal(0, sigma_a);
  b ~ normal(0, sigma_b);
  y ~ normal(y_hat, sigma_y);
}
```

it read

```
model {
  a ~ normal(mu_a, sigma_a);
  b ~ normal(mu_b, sigma_b);
  y ~ normal(y_hat, sigma_y);
}
```